# Iterate over two for lists and compare values

Tags: python

I have two lists of items I want to iterate over. One is a list of data class objects, Representatives, and another is a list of house transactions, dictionary. Later in the method, I create new Transaction data class objects that contain relevant information from the transactions list inside the house transaction dictionary.

This transactions list is a list of transactions for the given filing date. For example, you can have a house transaction with a filing date of 01/01/2021 and in that house transaction have multiple transactions (dictionary with stuff like amount, ticker, transaction type) in that transactions list (i.e. Selling PYPL stock, Buying MSFT stock, Partial Sale of CAT stock, etc.).

Each Representative has a Gov Track ID identifier that I want to use as a key for transactions they did for a one-to-many relationship. Since there can be multiple representatives with the same last name, I plan to use the representative's last name and district (both of these two attributes are found in my Representative data class and House Transaction dictionary) to link the two. There is a Gov Track ID attribute in my Transaction data class that will be populated with the Gov Track ID from the matched Representative.

Basically, iterate over all House Transactions in my House Transactions list and if the Last Name and District match with a Representative's Last Name and District, then populate the Gov Track ID in the Transaction data class object with the matched Gov Track ID from the Representative.

Would I have to use two for loops to itertate over both lists using something like zip()?

```
def extract_house_transactions(house_json_links, representatives):
"""
Cross-references house members last names to only extract transactions of sitting members of HOR
:param house_json_links:
:param representatives:
:return: representatives_transactions
"""
representatives_transactions = []
representatives_last_names = []

for representative in representatives:
    representatives_last_names.append(representative.last_name)

for link in house_json_links:
    house_transaction_request = requests.get(link)
    house_transactions = house_transaction_request.json()
    if house_transactions:
        for house_transaction in house_transactions:
            if house_transaction.get('last_name') in representatives_last_names:
                for transaction in house_transaction.get('transactions'):
                    if transaction.get('ticker') != '--':
                        tran = Transaction(house_transaction.get('first_name'), house_transaction.get('last_name'),
                                           house_transaction.get('source_ptr_link'),
                                           transaction.get('transaction_date'), transaction.get('transaction_type'),
                                           transaction.get('ticker'), transaction.get('amount'))
                        representatives_transactions.append(tran)
                        print(f"House Transaction: {tran}")

return representatives_transactions
```

This is what a Representative looks like:

```
Representative(first_name='Alma', last_name='Adams', gov_track_id='412607', party='D', leadership_role='None', seniority_level=10, state='NC', district='NC12', geo_id='3712')
```

This is what a House Transaction looks like:

```
{'prefix': 'Hon.', 'first_name': 'Raúl M.', 'last_name': 'Grijalva', 'suffix': None, 'name': 'Hon. Raúl M. Grijalva', 'filing_date': '12/20/2021', 'document_id': '20020062', 'year': 2021, 'district': 'AZ03', 'source_ptr_link': 'https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2021/20020062.pdf', 'transactions': [{'owner': 'self', 'transaction_date': '2021-12-17', 'ticker': 'CBOE', 'description': 'Cboe Global Markets Inc', 'transaction_type': 'sale_full', 'amount': '$1,001 - $15,000', 'cap_gains_over_200': False}], 'transcribed_by': 'Timothy Carambat'}
```

That transactions list in House Transactions can have multiple transactions in there.

This is what my custom Transaction data class looks like:

```
Transaction(first_name='Raúl M.', last_name='Grijalva', source_ptr_link='https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2021/20020062.pdf', transaction_date='2021-12-17', transaction_type='sale_full', ticker='CBOE', amount='$1,001 - $15,000')
```

The output should be the Gov Track ID attribute from the Representative data class on my custom Transaction data class if the last name and district from the current House Transaction in the loop matches any Representative with that same last name and district.

Comment: Can you provide examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Sounds like a join operation; you might want to look at using SQLite instead of two lists.

Comment: @Chris added more explanation to the OP.

Comment: @chepner this is all happening before any database inserts. The plan is to insert all Representatives and Transactions after the Transactions have been created/linked with the Gov Track Id. Are you saying I should insert the Representatives first (they are created before this process) and then when looping through the House Transactions just query the DB if the last name and district on the current House Transaction matched any Rep in the DB?